# Use ES6 classes as vuex store state in Nuxt

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js, es6-class

When I set *ES6 class* to state on my vuex store in nuxt I got following warn:

```
 WARN  Cannot stringify arbitrary non-POJOs EndPoint
```

and When I use object as state is works without warning.

So How can I use *ES6 classes* in my state.

My model:

```
export default class EndPoint {
    constructor(newEndPoints) {
        this.login = newEndPoints.login;
        this.status = newEndPoints.status;
    }
}
```

and mutate state here:

```
commit(CoreMutations.SET_ENDPOINTS, new EndPoint(response.data));
```

Using object:

```
const EndPoint = {
    endPoints(newEndPoints) {
        return {
            login: newEndPoints.login,
            status: newEndPoints.status
        };
    }
};
```

and mutate:

```
commit(CoreMutations.SET_ENDPOINTS, EndPoint.endPoints(response.data));
```

Comment: What does your `SET_ENDPOINTS` mutation do?

Comment: https://github.com/vuex-orm/vuex-orm/issues/255

Comment: Just new value to my state. of course before asking I searched and I saw that, but I don't use vuex orm.

Comment: That issue mentions the Nuxt fork of _devalue_ is the source of the warning. Have you tried adding a `toJSON` method to your class?

Comment: When I add `toJSON` method without body, warning gone, but why?

Comment: I suggest you read through that Github issue. There are direct links to the section of code in `nuxt/devalue` that trigger the warning

Comment: Ok, tnx for your favor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As discussion in comment add `toJSON` method in class solve the problem when setting state in client, but when set state in server, states will become `undefined`.
so adding this code solve the problem:

```
    toJSON() {
        return Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this).reduce((a, b) => {
            a[b] = this[b];
            return a;
        }, {});
    }
```